# How to execute pexpect spawn comand as sudo user?

Tags: python, pexpect

I'm trying to execute a pexpect spawn command as sudo and getting timeout error

```
import pexpect,os,commands,getpass
child = pexpect.spawn ('su - oracle -c "/home/Middleware/bin/emctl  status oms -details"')
child.expect("Enter Enterprise Manager Root (SYSMAN) Password :")
child.sendline("welcome1")
child.expect(pexpect.EOF, timeout=None)
cmd_show_data = child.before
cmd_output = cmd_show_data.split('\r\n')
for data in cmd_output:
    print data
```

Below is the execution output:

```
pexpect.TIMEOUT: Timeout exceeded in read_nonblocking().
<pexpect.spawn object at 0x9ae510>
version: 2.3 ($Revision: 399 $)
command: /bin/su
args: ['/bin/su', '-', 'oracle', '-c', '/home/Middleware/bin/emctl status oms -details']
searcher: searcher_re:
    0: re.compile("Enter Enterprise Manager Root (SYSMAN) Password :")
buffer (last 100 chars): , 2016 Oracle Corporation.  All rights reserved.
Enter Enterprise Manager Root (SYSMAN) Password :
before (last 100 chars): , 2016 Oracle Corporation.  All rights reserved.
Enter Enterprise Manager Root (SYSMAN) Password :
after: <class 'pexpect.TIMEOUT'>
```

Comment: if i change the child.expect("Enter Enterprise Manager Root (SYSMAN) Password :") as  expect child.expect('assword') then it is working.But want to pass the whole expected command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your search string doesn't match the output when compiled to a Regular Expression.

As per the [`spawn.expect`](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pexpect.html#pexpect.spawn.expect) documentation:

> The pattern can be a StringType, EOF, a compiled re, or a list of any
>   of those types. **Strings will be compiled to re types**.

The problem is the parenthesis, they are special characters in Regular Expressions and must be escaped with a backslash when intended to be treated as literals.

```
print(re.match("Enter Enterprise Manager Root (SYSMAN) Password :",
               "Enter Enterprise Manager Root (SYSMAN) Password :"))

# Prints: None

print(re.match("Enter Enterprise Manager Root \(SYSMAN\) Password :",
               "Enter Enterprise Manager Root (SYSMAN) Password :"))

# Prints: <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 49), match='Enter Enterprise Manager Root (SYSMAN) Password :>
```

Comment: Thanks shmee.It worked after escaped the special characters.By any chance do we have any option to debug pexpect commands step by step to know what output we are getting for each command?

Comment: @JayaprakashNagarajan You can check `child.before`. This will contain the last 100 characters read from the pty if either `child.expect("<pattern>")` returned or an exception has been raised. A better solution probably is to pass a file handle to one of the child's [`logfile`](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pexpect.html#pexpect.spawn.logfile) attributes. There's also a few examples for that in the [`spawn class`](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pexpect.html#spawn-class), but it does not have an anchor unfortunately.